# How to get number of logins per day from a timestamp table in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a table in MongoDB which looks like this:

USERID | EVENT TYPE | TIMESTAMP

Every time a user logs in, a new entry is added to this table. I want to retrieve a number of events from a given day and that day, so I want to get something like

01/01/2016 - 5 events

and so on

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {TIMESTAMP: timestamp}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$TIMESTAMP",
            events: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

1. The match says that it has to match the timestamp.
2. The group says "Group by TIMESTAMP and add 1 to a new field called events"

Just change the lowercase timestamp to your desired timestamp.

or if you want only one timestamp

```
db.testCollection.find({TIMESTAMP: timestamp})
```

--

Or you could change your schema to something like

```
{
    _id: userid,
    events: [
        {
            type: "",
            timestamp: timestamp
        }
    ]
}
```

This would use mongodb's option to create arrays instead of just plain values.

**Edit**

You have to make querys where timestamp is in between. Else this wont work as expected. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/STJEREM/ff136f6152ec88d1f11c)

Comment: How do I use it via the Doctrine ODM? I want to get all events from a given day, not a timestamp. Also how to pass this to the mongo shell? When I paste your code, nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about doctrine. If you want an answer in doctrine you should edit your question.

If you just want to count you can do the following:
https://gist.github.com/STJEREM/ff136f6152ec88d1f11c

The second timestamp is the same as the previous one, but with 24 hours added.